# Infrastructure service providers for scheduled java or c# program?

Tags: java, c#, azure, scheduled-tasks

I am doing a scheduled java or c# program, which collects data from different webpages (~100k pages) and saves them into database. It is supposed to run automatically every day and depending on network speed it takes couple of hours to run the program. So my question is:

- What kind of service providers there are for the infrastructure of my program?

I am not so familiar with servers and how to set/manage them so I would appreciate some serverless compute solutions. I have tried Azure Functions but it seems to be intended for faster programs.

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: What you mean _"I am doing a scheduled java or c# program"_? Both?

Comment: I mean that I am still able to choose the language if needed and the more important thing for me is the suitable platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this but it sounds like you would benefit a lot using [Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-technical-overview)
since you could actually run your data collection parallel and therefore also reduce the application total running time.